# Can't listen to 'ESC' in fullscreen

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, node.js, electron

I'm making a video player in an Electron/React app.
I want to exit fullscreen when the user presses ESC, but it seems that the ESC key is not triggering any event.

```js
// Player.js
const Player = (props) => {
    ...
    const handleFullscreen = () => {
        screenfull.toggle(playerContainerRef.current)
    }

    const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
        console.log(e.code)
    }

    return (
        ...
        <div ref={playerContainerRef} onKeyDown={handleKeyDown} ...>
            <div onDoubleClick={handleFullscreen} ...>
                <video .../>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
})
```

When not in fullscreen, `handleKeyDown()` prints every key I press, including ESC. But once I toggled/untoggled fullscreen, ESC is not triggering anymore.

### EDIT

This was my previous code:

```js
// App.js
const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    switch (e.code) {
        case 'Space':
            refs.playerRef.current?.play()
            break
        case 'ArrowLeft':
            refs.playerRef.current?.seekBackward()
            break
        case 'ArrowRight':
            refs.playerRef.current?.seekForward()
            break
        case 'NumpadAdd':
            refs.playerRef.current?.increaseSpeed()
            break
        case 'NumpadSubtract':
            refs.playerRef.current?.decreaseSpeed()
            break
        case 'Escape':
            console.log('Pressed ESC')
            break
        default:
            break
    }
}
```

But as I said, any condition above is triggered if the app has not entered fullscreen yet. Once fullscreen has been toggled and untoggled, the ESC condition is not working anymore

Comment: A Quick test here, ESC works fine in Fullscreen on Chrome, without a workable snippet we can only guess what's the problem.  I've a feeling it's likely focus issues, as your only listening to the DIV that now might not be focused.  Another idea is using `useEffect` attach the keypress event to the document instead.

Comment: The div is focused as when I press any other key (Q, Numpad1, Space, etc.), handleKeyDown() prints the key code. I've also tried with a useEffect in the main App.js (document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown)) but same issue, any key works except ESC.

Comment: `Electron/React`   Electron has it's own ways of going fullscreen, https://livebook.manning.com/book/cross-platform-desktop-applications/chapter-7/78

Answer (score 0):

@frOzie, I think, you might as well use the `document` object to listen for the keydown event globally, instead of relying on the keydown event of a specific element. I'd like to share my code.

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import screenfull from 'screenfull';

const Player = (props) => {
    const playerContainerRef = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
        const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
            // Check if the pressed key is ESC
            if (e.code === 'Escape' || e.key === 'Escape') {
                // Exit fullscreen if currently in fullscreen mode
                if (screenfull.isFullscreen) {
                    screenfull.exit();
                }
            }
        };

        // Add a global event listener for keydown on the document
        document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);

        // Clean up the event listener when the component is unmounted
        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
        };
    }, []);

    const handleFullscreen = () => {
        screenfull.toggle(playerContainerRef.current);
    };

    return (
        <div ref={playerContainerRef}>
            <div onDoubleClick={handleFullscreen}>
                <video />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Player;
```

This code uses the `useEffect` hook to add a global event listener for the keydown event on the `document` object.

!---
Please, make sure you have the neccessary dependencies installed, including `screenfull` if you haven't already:

```
npm install screenfull
```

Hope this maybe helpful.

Comment: Actually, this is the exact same code I was using earlier, but same issue, any key works except ESC... The only moment ESC works is when the app has not toggled fullscreen yet.

Comment: @frOzie, If the issue persists, I think maybe the fullscreen API or other elements in your application are intercepting the ESC key press. Here are a few additional suggestions:    
1. Instead of capturing key events on the container ```div```, try capturing them directly on the video element.
2. Check for Other Event Listeners
3. Listen for the fullscreen change event and see if it helps in capturing the ESC key.

Comment: I don't think this is `screenfull` related, as I also tried without additional packages (document.documentElement.requestFullscreen), and same issue. About your suggestions: 1. I tried capturing keys from main App.js, video wrapper and video element. 2. None of the listeners are capturing keys except this one. 3. I even tried to focus the wrapper/video every time I enter/exit fullscreen with a useEffect.

Comment: Given that you've already tried capturing the key events at different levels and it still doesn't work as expected, it's possible that Electron itself or the underlying Chromium engine is handling the ESC key differently during fullscreen mode.
I'll send another code and please check if is might be useful or less.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `keydown` event on the window object instead of the document object. This approach sometimes helps in capturing certain key events more reliably.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
        if (e.code === 'Escape' || e.key === 'Escape') {
            if (screenfull.isFullscreen) {
                screenfull.exit();
            }
        }
    };

    window.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);

    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
    };
}, []);
```

Hope this approach more helpful, @frOzie

Comment: Same issue. Event is only triggering before entering fullscreen... I guess I'll bind F11 instead of ESC as I'm going crazy.

Comment: Ha, I see. So you mean, pressing F11 is all ok?

Comment: Yes, as any other key. It will remain a mystery for now...